# gmail-api php without UI

Tags: php, cron, gmail-api

I've been working on this for 3 days now, trying various methods, hunting through the gmail api docs and stackoverflow, but I'm still not sure if it's even possible.

I'm trying to send email with the gmail api in a cron-style process. (not literally cron, but similar).  So there is no user interaction.

I set up credentials on the https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials page, but when I try to use it, I get errors.  I also ran the quickstart.php from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php#step_2_install_the_google_client_library but that seems that the credentials it creates expire after 3600 seconds.  I'm also not even sure how to use those as it doesn't have similar keys as the other credential file.

And then I saw on the credentials page, if you try to create a new set of credentials for the gmail api, for a cron-job, it won't let you.  It simply says "User data cannot be accessed from a platform without a UI because it requires user interaction for sign-in."

My question is, is it even possibly to run a cron job to send email with the gmail api without building my own classes that implement curl to read and scrape web pages?

Edit: I appreciate everyone's help but I'm just looking to see if anyone has actually done it.  So far, no one's admitting it.  I've looked at the service level credentials. I've looked at the user level credentials. I've tried the quick-start.  The quick start works, but even using the result immediately to send an email fails with a login failure.

I've read the documentation about refreshing the key as well.

It just seems to me that google has made so much available to the api that they may have forgotten doing anything without user interaction.  Hey, I get it.  Trying to write for everything is complicated.  I'm not complaining. I'm seriously only asking if anyone can even actually use gmail for this.

Comment: You can use Gmail's SMTP.

Comment: You mean the gmail-api, which I'm asking about?  Or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can request an offline access the first time the user logs in and refresh it when the access token expires. You have to ask the user to login the first time though.

First, before generating the login url, you need to set the access type to 'offline'. To do that, add the following line of code before calling `$this->client->createAuthUrl()`.

```
$this->client->setAccessType($accessType);
```

That will prompt the user for offline access the first time they're authenticating. Then, in your callback function, you should authenticate the user based on the received code and get the refresh token:

```
$this->client->authenticate($code);
$tokens = $this->client->getAccessToken();
$refresh_token = $tokens->refresh_token;
```

Save the refresh_token in your database and you will be able to create new access token every time it expires. You do that with the following code:

```
$this->client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
```

**Note**: This answer is based on Google's PHP SDK and the client is their client object. I created a wrapper for their API that you might find useful and easier for implementation. You can check it [here](https://github.com/adevait/GmailPHP), it has most of the functions covered.

Comment: I'm going through your examples, but it's more UI and forms. It doesn't seem like it's really doing what I'm asking.  All I want to know is if it's even possible to use the gmail api (oAuth 2.0) to send mail from a cron job.  If it is, then it would be great if someone had a simply straight-forward example of how to do it.   Right now I'm using the service level credentials I created, I create a new Google_Client(), create the application name, set the client secret, the scopes, grab the service from the client, and try to send an email. Always login failure though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the the Gmail API specifically but if you are using oAuth to get the credentials there is usually a refresh token that you can use to renew your credentials (basically get a new set) programmaticly. You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps).

Edit:
You need the UI the first time you get the token information. This can be done by a button in the settings or something that stores the returned info in a permanent place like a database. Then for the 'cron' type calls you reference the access token or if expired use the refresh token to get a new access token.

Comment: Thanks.  It suggests it can do it, but doesn't seem to explicitly say so.  It's also conflicting with the info on the create credentials page that say "User data cannot be accessed from a platform without a UI because it requires user interaction for sign-in."  I'm really hoping someone who has done this with the gmail api will chime in.

Comment: I've been attempting that but I still get a not logged in error.  I gotta say, this would be a lot simpler if could find a sample that does it from the start, or if someone who's actually succeeded with it could confirm that it IS possible.  I'm seriously suspicious that it was just copied over from the android authorization system, and not designed to be able to be used by cron jobs.

Comment: @jim Have you checked out [Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token)?

Comment: Sir. Egole: yes.  It's not helping.  No matter what I do, I get authorization errors.  This is why I'm asking if anyone has actually done this.